# the parameterized query'(@username nvarchar(8),@password nvarchar(8), @Fullname nvarchar(' expects the parameter '@id', which was not supplied

Tags: sql, sql-server

Whats wrong with this code? the error shows in cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4Olg.jpg)

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode - please add your code **as properly formatted text** - not as a screenshot ....

Comment: One thing that is wrong is that you store a password as clear text in your database. This however is not giving you an exception.

Answer (score 0):

There is minimum 2 problem with this code.

1.) Your password is in plaintext and you send it to the database in plaintext. Biggest security risk ever...

2.) If you want to use parametrized query you should write a stored procedure on database side and send the parameters for it.
Example here: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/using-stored-procedures-with-Asp-Net/

+1.) Add your code as properly formatted text, not as a screenshot.